# Asp.net Mvc ,Crystal Reports and Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, crystal-reports

I have few question regarding to Crystal reports and Azure VM

1. Is crystal reports is free if I am designing Reports in the Visual studio 2013,
2. If I want to deploy my application on Azure Virtual Machine having Crystal reports, so is there is any extra charges for Crystal reports.
3. Is Crystal Reports Runtime is free on Azure

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Download-Crystal-Reports-for-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx)

Crystal reports is free and will only work if your version of Visual Studio is not the express edition.

2. No, there would not be any charges
3. Runtime is not on azure, SAP purchased crystal reports and the developer runtime is free to download.

Answer (score 0):

kindly please check this link,

it was free before 2011 but not after 2011, you have to use there designing tool, or you have to buy license if you are exposing you application on the internet.

[Crystal report license](http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-reports/implement/licensing.html)